# Hive -YeardayFromDate function

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hiveql

in Hive, How to I get the YeardayFromDate function? 
eg:- if my date is 2018-01-23--answer should be 23,
if my date is 2018-02-25--answer should be 56.
for 2018-12-31--answershould be 365
.Basically I need to get day number of the year

Comment: have you try on your own or you just asking?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `date_format` UDF in hive to get the day of the year if your date is in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`

```
select date_format("2018-02-25",'D'); -- 56
```